# Two R scripts with same code: one gives result, other throws error

Tags: r, debugging

I have two identical R scripts; however, when I run each, one works but the other throws an error. I run each in different R sessions and clear memory before running them.

I have not been able to find an answer as to why this may be the case.

Perhaps someone else has had this issue and knows why it is occurring?

## Working script

```
library(investr)
library(mgcv) 
library(rootSolve)
library(scam)

inv.predict2 <- function(object, y, x.name, interval = FALSE, 
                     lower, upper, level = 0.95,...) {
.fun1 <- function(x) {
    predFit(object, newdata = setNames(data.frame(x), x.name)) - y
}
.fun2 <- function(x) {
   predFit(object, newdata = setNames(data.frame(x), x.name), 
   interval = "confidence")[, "upr"] - y
   }
.fun3 <- function(x) {
   predFit(object, newdata = setNames(data.frame(x), x.name), 
        interval = "confidence")[, "lwr"] - y
 }
 x0.est <- uniroot.all(lower = lower, upper = upper, ..., f = .fun1)
      res <- if (interval) {
          lwr <- uniroot.all(lower = lower, upper = x0.est, ..., f = .fun2)
          upr <- uniroot.all(lower = x0.est, upper = upper, ..., f = .fun3)
          lwr <- min(c(lwr, upr))
          upr <- max(c(lwr, upr))
c("estimate" = x0.est, "lower" = lwr, "upper" = upr)
} else {
x0.est
}
res
}

predFit.gam <- function(object, newdata, type = c("link", "response"), 
                    interval = c("none", "confidence", "prediction"), 
                    level = 0.95, ...) {
type <- match.arg(type)
interval <- match.arg(interval)
res <- if (interval == "none") {
predict.gam(object, newdata = newdata, type = type, ...)
} else if (interval == "confidence") {
pred <- predict.gam(object, newdata = newdata, se.fit = TRUE, type = "link", 
                ...)
out <- cbind("fit" = pred$fit,
             "lwr" = pred$fit - pred$se.fit * stats::qnorm((level + 1) / 2),
             "upr" = pred$fit + pred$se.fit * stats::qnorm((level + 1) / 2))
if (type == "response") {
  out <- apply(out, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) {
    stats::family(object)$linkinv(x)
  })
}
out
} else {
stop("Prediction intervals are currently not supported for GAMs.")
}
res
}

predFit.scam <- function(object, newdata, type = c("link", "response"), 
                    interval = c("none", "confidence", "prediction"), 
                    level = 0.95, ...) {
    type <- match.arg(type)
    interval <- match.arg(interval)
    res <- if (interval == "none") {
predict.scam(object, newdata = newdata, type = type, ...)
} else if (interval == "confidence") {
pred <- predict.scam(object, newdata = newdata, se.fit = TRUE, type = "link", 
                ...)
out <- cbind("fit" = pred$fit,
             "lwr" = pred$fit - pred$se.fit * stats::qnorm((level + 1) / 2),
             "upr" = pred$fit + pred$se.fit * stats::qnorm((level + 1) / 2))
if (type == "response") {
  out <- apply(out, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) {
    stats::family(object)$linkinv(x)
  })
}
out
} else {
stop("Prediction intervals are currently not supported for SCAMs.")
}
res
}


ptm <- proc.time() 

set.seed(1)

# Rprof()

K <- 1 
N <- 100 
Hstar <- 10

perms <- 10000 

specs <- 1:N 

pop <- array(dim = c(c(perms, N), K))

haps <- as.character(1:Hstar)

probs <- rep(1/Hstar, Hstar) 

x <- c(1:3)
y <- c(3:5)

for(j in 1:perms){
    for(i in 1:K){
        if(i == 1){
        pop[j, specs, i] <- sample(haps, size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs)
    }
        else{
            pop[j ,, 1] <- sample(haps[x], size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[x])
            pop[j ,, 2] <- sample(haps[y], size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[y])
        }
}
}

HAC.mat <- array(dim = c(c(perms, N), K))

for(k in specs){
    for(j in 1:perms){
        for(i in 1:K){
            ind.index <- sample(specs, size = k, replace = FALSE)
            hap.plot <- pop[sample(1:nrow(pop), size = 1, replace = TRUE), ind.index, sample(1:K, size = 1, replace = TRUE)] 
            HAC.mat[j, k, i] <- length(unique(hap.plot))
    }
}
}

means <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, mean)
lower <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.025))
upper <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.975))

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

plot(specs, means, type = "n", xlab = "Specimens sampled", ylab = "Unique haplotypes", ylim = c(1, Hstar))
polygon(x = c(specs, rev(specs)), y = c(lower, rev(upper)), col = "gray")
lines(specs, means, lwd = 2)
HAC.bar <- barplot(N*probs, xlab = "Unique haplotypes", ylab = "Specimens sampled", names.arg = 1:Hstar)

# summaryRprof()

proc.time() - ptm

d <- data.frame(specs, means)

HAC.tp <- gam(means ~ s(specs, bs = "tp", k = 20), optimizer = c("outer", "bfgs"), data = d) # thin plate spline

HAC.tp <- inv.predict2(HAC.tp, y = Hstar, x.name = "specs", interval = TRUE, lower = 1, upper = 1000000)
HAC.tp
```

## Non-working script

```
library(investr) 
library(mgcv) 
library(rootSolve)
library(scam) 

inv.predict2 <- function(object, y, x.name, interval = FALSE, 
                     lower, upper, level = 0.95,...) {
.fun1 <- function(x) {
predFit(object, newdata = setNames(data.frame(x), x.name)) - y
}
.fun2 <- function(x) {
predFit(object, newdata = setNames(data.frame(x), x.name), 
        interval = "confidence")[, "upr"] - y
}
.fun3 <- function(x) {
predFit(object, newdata = setNames(data.frame(x), x.name), 
        interval = "confidence")[, "lwr"] - y
}
x0.est <- uniroot.all(lower = lower, upper = upper, ..., f = .fun1)
res <- if (interval) {
lwr <- uniroot.all(lower = lower, upper = x0.est, ..., f = .fun2)
upr <- uniroot(lower = x0.est, upper = upper, ..., f = .fun3)
lwr <- min(c(lwr, upr))
upr <- max(c(lwr, upr))
c("estimate" = x0.est, "lower" = lwr, "upper" = upr)
} else {
x0.est
}
res
}

predFit.gam <- function(object, newdata, type = c("link", "response"), 
                    interval = c("none", "confidence", "prediction"), 
                    level = 0.95, ...) {
type <- match.arg(type)
interval <- match.arg(interval)
res <- if (interval == "none") {
predict.gam(object, newdata = newdata, type = type, ...)
} else if (interval == "confidence") {
pred <- predict.gam(object, newdata = newdata, se.fit = TRUE, type = "link", 
                ...)
out <- cbind("fit" = pred$fit,
             "lwr" = pred$fit - pred$se.fit * stats::qnorm((level + 1) / 2),
             "upr" = pred$fit + pred$se.fit * stats::qnorm((level + 1) / 2))
if (type == "response") {
  out <- apply(out, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) {
    stats::family(object)$linkinv(x)
  })
}
out
} else {
stop("Prediction intervals are currently not supported for GAMs.")
}
res
}

predFit.scam <- function(object, newdata, type = c("link", "response"), 
                    interval = c("none", "confidence", "prediction"), 
                    level = 0.95, ...) {
    type <- match.arg(type)
    interval <- match.arg(interval)
    res <- if (interval == "none") {
predict.scam(object, newdata = newdata, type = type, ...)
} else if (interval == "confidence") {
pred <- predict.scam(object, newdata = newdata, se.fit = TRUE, type = "link", 
                ...)
out <- cbind("fit" = pred$fit,
             "lwr" = pred$fit - pred$se.fit * stats::qnorm((level + 1) / 2),
             "upr" = pred$fit + pred$se.fit * stats::qnorm((level + 1) / 2))
if (type == "response") {
  out <- apply(out, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) {
    stats::family(object)$linkinv(x)
  })
}
out
} else {
stop("Prediction intervals are currently not supported for SCAMs.")
}
res
}

ptm <- proc.time() 

set.seed(1)

# Rprof()

K <- 1 

N <- 100 

Hstar <- 10

perms <- 10000

specs <- 1:N 

pop <- array(dim = c(c(perms, N), K))

haps <- as.character(1:Hstar)

probs <- rep(1/Hstar, Hstar) 

s1 <- c(1:6)

s2 <- c(7:10)

for(j in 1:perms){
    for(i in 1:K){ 
        if(i == 1){
            pop[j, specs, i] <- sample(haps, size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs)
    }
        else{
            pop[j ,, 1] <- sample(haps[s1], size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[s1])
            pop[j ,, 2] <- sample(haps[s2], size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[s2])
        }
}
}

HAC.mat <- array(dim = c(c(perms, N), K))

for(k in specs){
    for(j in 1:perms){
        for(i in 1:K){ 
            ind.index <- sample(specs, size = k, replace = FALSE) 
            hap.plot <- pop[sample(1:nrow(pop), size = 1, replace = TRUE), ind.index, sample(1:K, size = 1, replace = TRUE)]
            HAC.mat[j, k, i] <- length(unique(hap.plot)) 
    }
}
}

means <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, mean)
lower <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.025))
upper <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.975))

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

plot(specs, means, type = "n", xlab = "Specimens sampled", ylab = "Unique haplotypes", ylim = c(1, Hstar))
polygon(x = c(specs, rev(specs)), y = c(lower, rev(upper)), col = "gray")
lines(specs, means, lwd = 2)
HAC.bar <- barplot(N*probs, xlab = "Unique haplotypes", ylab = "Specimens sampled", names.arg = 1:Hstar)

# summaryRprof()

proc.time() - ptm

d <- data.frame(specs, means)

HAC.tp <- gam(means ~ s(specs, bs = "tp", k = 20), optimizer = c("outer", "bfgs"), data = d) # thin plate spline
summary(HAC.tp)
plot(HAC.tp)

HAC.tp <- inv.predict2(HAC.tp, y = Hstar, x.name = "specs", interval = TRUE, lower = 1, upper = 1000000)
HAC.tp
```

Comment: It's helpful to paste the script here.

Comment: Just guessing without looking at the code. Maybe an error thrown by a random sampling/selection? Try to set.seed().

Comment: Looking at the script might be helpful to provide a resolution.

Comment: I have added the scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two scripts are not identical.

In line 22, in the working script, you have `uniroot.all()` and in the non-working script you have `uniroot()`. I changed the non-working to `uniroot.all()` and it completed without any errors (but I have absolutely no idea if the results are correct).

Also - if its useful information, around line 102, you have differences in (working):

```
x <- c(1:3)
y <- c(3:5)
```

(Non-working):

```
s1 <- c(1:6)

s2 <- c(7:10)
```

This difference is probably less important, but just thought I would let you know.

Finally, for the future, I would recommend using BeyondCompare, or Atom. (I think I remember liking Atom better, but its been a while, since we have to use BC here...) These two programs (or many other similar alternatives) can help you compare text (or files or folders) to easily find differences.

Comment: Thank you -- not sure how that happened. Totally missed that... I know about the difference at line 102 but it doesn't affect results.I've never heard of beyondCompare and Atom before... I'll definitely check them out!

Comment: No Prob! Glad I could finally ANSWER a question, instead of always asking them!

Comment: I'm ALWAYS asking questions too!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try one of these to explore the debugging functionality?

```
    traceback() 
    browser()
```

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html